# Skipping elements in a List Python

Tags: python

I'm new to programming and I'm trying to do the codingbat.com problems to start. I came across this problem:

Given an array calculate the sum except when there is a 13 in the array. If there is a 13 in the array, skip the 13 and the number immediately following it. For example [1,2,13,5,1] should yield 4 (since the 13 and the 5s are skipped).

This is what I have so far. My problem is that I don't know what to do when there are multiple 13s...And I would like to learn coding efficiently. Can you guys help? (I'm using python 3.2) Thanks!

```
def pos(nums):
    for i in nums:
        if i == 13:
            return nums.index(13)
    return False

def sum13(lis):
    if pos(lis)!= False:
        return sum(lis[:pos(lis)])+sum(lis[pos(lis)+1:])
    else:
        return sum(lis)
```

Comment: Your example should really yield `4`, right?  1+2+1 = 4.

Comment: @WillBuddha I think the behavior of consecutive 13s is a little ambiguous, actually.  Should a 13 skip the subsequent 13's effect?

Comment: Let's assume a 13 doesn't skip the effect of a consecutive 13 so that [13,13,1,4] yields a 4.

Comment: `if foo != False:` is redundant; just use `if foo:`

Comment: The answer you accepted works here as well: http://codingbat.com/prob/p108886

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One tricky thing to notice is something like this: [1, 13, 13, 2, 3]

You need to skip `2` too

```
def getSum(l):
    sum = 0
    skip = False
    for i in l:
         if i == 13:
             skip = True
             continue
         if skip:
             skip = False
             continue
         sum += i
    return sum
```

**Explanation**:

You go through the items in the list one by one

Each time you

- First check if it's 13, if it is, then you mark `skip` as `True`, so that you can also skip next item.
- Second, you check if `skip` is `True`, if it is, which means it's a item right after 13, so you need to skip this one too, and you also need to set `skip` back to `False` so that you don't skip next item.
- Finally, if it's not either case above, you add the value up to `sum`

Comment: Can you explain this iteration for a newb like me?

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize if skip: implied if skip = True...Thanks!

Comment: Ah I like this answer I understand it! (The zip function is too advanced for me right now) thanks again!

Comment: `elif` would be better here than `continue`

Comment: Note to OP: this answer works for this as well: http://codingbat.com/prob/p108886

Comment: @georg what do you mean?

Answer (score 6):

You can use the *zip* function to loop the values in pairs:

```
def special_sum(numbers):
    s = 0
    for (prev, current) in zip([None] + numbers[:-1], numbers):
        if prev != 13 and current != 13:
            s += current
    return s
```

or you can do a oneliner:

```
def special_sum(numbers):
    return sum(current for (prev, current) in zip([None] + numbers[:-1], numbers)
               if prev != 13 and current != 13)
```

You can also use iterators:

```
from itertools import izip, chain
def special_sum(numbers):
    return sum(current for (prev, current) in izip(chain([None], numbers), numbers)
               if prev != 13 and current != 13)
```

(the first list in the *izip* is longer than the second, *zip* and *izip* ignore the extra values).

Comment: Wow Thanks! This one looks like it would work and after a long look I now understand it. Thanks!

Comment: This code is very memory inefficient, and will not work with iterators :)

Answer (score 3):

Use a while loop to walk through the list, incrementing `i` manually.  On each iteration, if you encounter a 13, increment `i` twice; otherwise, add the value to a running sum and increment `i` once.

```
def skip13s(l):
    i = 0
    s = 0
    while (i < len(l)):
        if l[i] == 13:
            i += 1
        else:
            s += l[i]
        i += 1
    return s
```

Answer (score 2):

Some FP-style :)

```
def add_but_skip_13_and_next(acc, x):
    prev, sum_ = acc
    if prev != 13 and x != 13:
        sum_ += x
    return x, sum_

filter_and_sum = lambda l: reduce(add_but_skip_13_and_next, l, (0,0))[1]

>>> print filter_and_sum([13,13,1,4])
4
>>> print filter_and_sum([1,2,13,5,13,13,-9,13,13,13,13,13,1,1])
4
```

This code works for any iterator, even it not provide the random access (direct indexing) - socket for example :)

Oneliner :)

```
>>> filter_and_sum = lambda l: reduce(
...     lambda acc, x: (x, acc[1] + (x if x != 13 and acc[0] != 13 else 0)),
...     l, (0,0))[1]
>>> print filter_and_sum([1,2,13,5,13,13,-9,13,13,13,13,13,1,1])
4
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the most compact solution:

```
def triskaidekaphobicSum(sequence):
    return sum(sequence[i] for i in range(len(sequence))
               if sequence[i] != 13 and (i == 0 or sequence[i-1] != 13))
```

This uses the builtin sum() function on a generator expression. The generator produces all the elements in the sequence as long as they are not 13, or immediately following a 13. The extra "or" condition is to handle the first item in the sequence (which has no previous item).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `while` loop to treat multiple `13`.

```
def sum13(lis):
    while pos(lis):
        if pos(lis) == len(lis) - 1:
            lis = lis[:pos(lis)]
        else:
            lis = lis[:pos(lis)]+lis[pos(lis)+1:]

    return sum(lis)
```

Comment: For some reason this didn't work for [13,1,2,13,2,1,13]...It gave 45 as the sum

Comment: I think it is because the latest element in the list is 13.So I edited my code.

Answer (score 0):

```
def skipAndAddFun(inputVal, skipList):
   sum = 0
   for i in inputVal:
        if not i in skipList:
            sum += i
    return sum
```

Usage:

```
skipAndAddFun([1,2,13,5,1], [13, 5])
4
```

This simple function will be a generic solution for your question.