# Is there a better way to exclude elements from the Python list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Looking for a cleaner and more optimal solution in Python for -

Return the sum of the numbers in the array, returning 0 for an empty array.
Except the number 13 is very unlucky, so it does not count and numbers that come immediately after a 13 also do not count.

sum13([1, 2, 2, 1]) → 6

sum13([1, 1]) → 2

sum13([1, 2, 2, 1, 13]) → 6

```
    def sum13(nums):
      indexes_list = [i for i,v in enumerate(nums) if v==13 ]
      adjacent_indexes_list = [x+1 for x in indexes_list if x+1 < len(nums)]
      ignore_list = indexes_list + adjacent_indexes_list
      desired_nums = [v for i,v in enumerate(nums) if i not in (ignore_list) ]
      return sum(desired_nums)
```

Comment: That looks lengthy and too much iteration, but readable, imho.

Comment: Exact duplicate of [Skipping elements in a List Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11059910/skipping-elements-in-a-list-python)

Comment: How many other variants/refactor's have you come up with? can you show them so we don't duplicate your efforts?  why don't you consider this solution optimal?

Comment: Why did you use comprehensions? If you use a *regular* for loop, you'll have more control.

Answer (score 0):

You can just `break` the iteration if number 13 was found.

```
def sum13(nums):
    if nums:
        res = []
        for num in nums:
            if num != 13:
                res.append(num)
            else:
                break
        return sum(res)
    return 0
```